# Is there any way to assign values from MYSQL query in flask to an HTML document?

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask, jinja2

I am working on a webpage where I do a query in the Python flask app. Following is the query I ran:

```
cur.execute("SELECT sum(quantity) FROM pydb.products GROUP BY category")
```

Which Results in: [image: This is the output from the query]

I want to access these data one by one to assign them to the following Quantity Part of the HTML code:

```html
<ul id="autoWidth" class="cs-hidden">
          <li class="item-a">
              <div class="box">
                  <div class="slide-img">
                    <img src="static/images/1.webp" alt="1" />
                    <div class="overlay">
                      <a href="/details/camera" class="details-btn">View Details</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            
                  <div class="detail-box">
                    <div class="type">
                      <a href="#">Camera & Camcorders</a>
                      <span> </span>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="quantity">  </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
          </li>
          <li class="item-b">
              <div class="box">
                  <div class="slide-img">
                    <img src="static/images/2.jfif" alt="2" />
                    <div class="overlay">
                      <a href="/details/laptop" class="details-btn">View Details</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            
                  <div class="detail-box">
                    <div class="type">
                      <a href="#">Laptops</a>
                      <span>  </span>
                    </div>
            
                    <a href="#" class="quantity"> </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
          </li>
          </ul>
```

Comment: all tutorials show it.

Comment: They show it through iterations. I need to access individual columns brother @furas

Comment: `all_rows = cur.fetch()` and later `return render_tempalte("file.html", data=all_rows)` and inside `HTML` use `{% for ... %}` to generate HTML

Comment: `column` means `many rows` so you can iterate it.

Comment: Yes, I have already use this to generate the whole table. But i need individual cells now.

Comment: I still don't understand what is the problem to iterate result to get row and later iterate row to get cell in row. For flask it always the same - it doesn't matter if you get many rows, one row, or one column.

Comment: So you want to print the quantity corresponding to the category of each product? How about load the results of your query into a dict, where the dict key is the category name. You'd need to add a column `category` to your query so you can associate each category with its sum value. Then in your HTML in each table cell you just reference the dict by the category of the product.

Comment: Jinja template ruins my image slider whenever i use Iteration

Comment: it is different problem - it has nothing to do with SQL but with your structure in HTML

Comment: BTW: maybe you should fetch two columns `SELECT category, sum(quantity)` - this way you will know which value is for which category

Comment: @BillKarwin yes brother.  I don't know how to do that.  I am a newbie

Comment: @furas yes brother I have used SELECT category, sum(quantity) this too. But since I only need the Quantity only I dont really require the category in the app itself.

Comment: Then how do you know in the app which quantity is for which category?

Comment: I will just hard code it @BillKarwin since its only 5 catergories

Comment: If you hard code it then you need as in first comment `all_rows = cur.fetch()` and later `return render_tempalte("file.html", data=all_rows)` and inside `HTML` you need to use indexes `data[0][0]` to get first value from first row (it uses numbers `[row][column]`)

Comment: @furas, brother, You just solved my problem. Take hugs and love. Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may see in many tutorials:

Get data from database

```
all_rows = cur.fetch()
```

Send data to template

```
render_tempalte("file.html", data=all_rows)
```

And inside HTML you may use `for`-loops to display it (I skip tags).

```
{% for row in data %}
   {% for item in row %}
      {{ item }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But you may also access item usings indexes `[row][column]`

```
{{ data[0][0] }}

{{ data[1][0] }}
```

Or you may modify data before sending to template

```
render_tempalte("file.html", laptops=all_rows[0][0], others=all_rows[1][0])
```

and later

```
{{ laptops }}

{{ others }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother! Appreciate it!! This has been a great help!